# Too many recently failed requests for ad unit ID (AdMob)

Tags: flutter, admob

`Too many recently failed requests for ad unit ID: ca-app-pub-XXXX. You must wait a few seconds before making another ad request.`

I erased all contents of simulator and restarted it, but it didn't work at all. I guess it might be happened because of previous failed requests, I have no idea how to solve it. I just waited a minutes, but ad didn't show up. Also I don't understand what `you must wait a few seconds before making another ad request` means. Has anyone solved this?

```
import 'package:admob_flutter/admob_flutter.dart';

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
AdmobBannerSize bannerSize;
AdmobInterstitial interstitialAd;

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Admob.initialize(Platform.isIOS
        ? 'ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
        : 'ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
    interstitialAd = AdmobInterstitial(
      adUnitId: Platform.isIOS
          ? 'ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
          : 'ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
      listener: (AdmobAdEvent event, Map<String, dynamic> args) {
        print('$event');
        if (event == AdmobAdEvent.closed) {
          interstitialAd.load();
        }
      },
    );
    interstitialAd.load();
  }


 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        body: ListView(children: <Widget>[
           Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 50.0,
              height: 50,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, right: 25, top: 5),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xFF337B6D),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
              child: AdmobBanner(
                adUnitId: Platform.isIOS
                    ? 'ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
                    : 'ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                adSize: AdmobBannerSize.BANNER,
                listener: (AdmobAdEvent event, Map<String, dynamic> args) {
                  print('$event');
                },
              )
            )
          ]
        )
}
```

Comment: You should show code where is this request ad so that I can you help.

Comment: @Captivity Thanks for your comment. As you said, I added code related with admob. Please let me know any problems.

Comment: @Ryanldea Have You the same `adUnitId` for the `interstitialAd` and `AdmobBanner`? Maybe this is problem.

Comment: @Captivity Of course. I used the same `adUnitId` for both. but error still came up.

Comment: This is problem. Diffrent ads must have diffrent adUnitId

Comment: In AdMob panel you must create new diffrent advertising unit for for each ads.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've shared doesn't have any obvious issues. The error thrown from AdMob seems to come from the traffic of requests. You can also check if the Ad is being loaded multiple times using the `AdListener.onAdLoaded()` callback. This is a known issue as mentioned in this [thread](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter/issues/155).